# Shiv'a VaChamishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred fifty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yitzchak was 157 when Yaakov began his journey home.

123 when Yaakov left (sourced previously in MiYodeya)

14 years that Yaakov was in Yeshivas S&E

20 years Yaakov was by Lavan